# Set "batchSize" per trigger with Azure Function Queue

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, message-queue

I have an .NET Azure Function with several Queue Triggers. I have my host.json file configured (see below) which dequeues up to 4 messages at a time.

```
{
    "queues": {
        "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:03",
        "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "batchSize": 4,
        "maxDequeueCount": 5,
        "newBatchThreshold": 2,
        "messageEncoding": "base64"
    }
}
```

This is fine for all the triggers except one where I need to dequeue 1 message at a time.

Is it possible to override the "batchSize" property on a per trigger basis? My alternative is to split this trigger out into it's own function.

From what I've researched, some suggest this might be possible in a functions.json file. I don't have a functions.json file though, so not sure where to start here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dequeue different messages for specific queue triggers, ***You need to create two separate Functions with different batchSize like below***:-

My message queues:-

**Queue-1** :

[image]

**Queue-2** :

[image]

**Code** :

***function1.cs*** :

```c
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("QueueTriggerFunction1")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("kaqueue1", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string myQueueItem,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Function1 processed: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

***Function1/host.json*** :

```json
{
  "queues": {
    "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:03",
    "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
    "batchSize": 4,
    "maxDequeueCount": 5,
    "newBatchThreshold": 2,
    "messageEncoding": "base64"
  }
}
```

***Function2/Function2.cs*** :

```c
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static class Function2
{
    [FunctionName("QueueTriggerFunction2")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("kaqueue2", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string myQueueItem,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Function2 processed: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

***Function2/host.json*** :

```json
{
  "queues": {
    "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:03",
    "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
    "batchSize": 1, 
    "maxDequeueCount": 5,
    "newBatchThreshold": 2,
    "messageEncoding": "base64"
  }
}
```

***local.settings.json*** :

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<connec_string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

**Output** :

[image]

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the code below in your Function.cs to set the batchSize dynamically :

Message queues :

[image]

**Code** :

```c
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
public static class MyQueueFunction
{
    [FunctionName("MyQueueFunction")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("kaqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string message,
        int dequeueCount,
        ILogger log)
    {
        int batchSize = 4;        
        {
            batchSize = 1; 
                   }
            log.LogInformation($"Processing message: {message} with batch size: {batchSize}");
            for (int j = 0; j < batchSize; j++)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** :

[image]